# Spring Integration DSL equivalent for 'int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter' with 'subscription-shared' option

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

we have a configuration from a MessageDrivenChannelAdapter like this

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="..."
                                        connection-factory="..."
                                        destination-name="..."
                                        pub-sub-domain="true"
                                        subscription-name="..."
                                        subscription-shared="true"
                                        subscription-durable="true"
                                        auto-startup="..."
                                        error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

I have been able to replicate most of the configuration:

```
 JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec<JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec, DefaultMessageListenerContainer> destination = Jms
        .messageDrivenChannelAdapter([connection-factory])
        .destination([destination-name])
        .autoStartup([auto-startup])
        .configureListenerContainer(c -> c
           .pubSubDomain(true)
           .subscriptionDurable(true)
           .durableSubscriptionName([subscription-name])
        )
        .errorChannel(errorChannel);
```

But I can't find in the DSL how to mark the subscription as shared

How this should be achieved?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh! I think we have just missed to expose an option for the `public void setSubscriptionShared(boolean subscriptionShared) {`.

Please, raise a JIRA ASAP and we will fix it in the release today.

As a workaround I suggest to use fallback to the `AbstractMessageListenerContainer`:

```
.configureListenerContainer(c -> { c
       .pubSubDomain(true)
       .subscriptionDurable(true)
       .durableSubscriptionName([subscription-name]);
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = c.get();
        messageListenerContainer.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        }
     )
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps, raising the issue.
No chance this will be backported in the DSL for Spring Integration DSL 1.3.x?

Comment: I think really no chances: we are back-porting only critical bugs without any workarounds